# htaccess RewriteRule no redirect, first rule works, second not

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have no clue why my first rule works, but my second not.

I want to change several existing Folders on my webspace to use php scripts in other Folders. no redirect.

https://url.com/test/this-is-a-nice-site/  should load php from https://url.com/media/this-is-a-nice-site/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/testT1/(.*)$ /media/testt1/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/this-is-a-nice-site/(.*)$ /media/this-is-a-nice-site/$1 [L]
```

The First Rule works, when I go to https://url.com/test/testT1/ I get the files/php from /media/testt1/

But when I try https://url.com/test/this-is-a-nice-site/ , I get a 301 redirect to https://url.com/media/this-is-a-nice-site/

I don't get why, the Rule is the same, both Folders test/testH3/ and test/this-is-a-nice-site/ exists.

I couldn't find anything that helps.

Comment: What's the problem? That it's 301 redirecting? You must have some other rules or routing in your application, surely?

Comment: Yes, the first Rule will https://url.com/test/testT1/ 200 , the second 301 to https://url.com/media/this-is-a-nice-site/ , i want both 200. There is only a http to https code above 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Those rules will not perform an external redirection. Either you have some other component which is responsible for that (maybe application logic?) or you are looking at a cached result.